# Channel:form tags not working

Tags: safecracker

I am new to expression engine, I am trying to create a form with the channel:form tags but whatever I put in the tags don't show up on the website.  Do I have to activate channel form tags in the settings somewhere?

Comment: You'll need to provide us with more information. What EE version are you using, and can you share your code tags so we can see what you've been trying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few settings from backend to work with Channel form. You can find these settings from **Settings** tab of **Channel Manager**. Please see screenshot below to change Channel form settings. I hope this will work for you.

[image]